# Find element by xpath doesn't work when macro used, Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm running into an issue where when I try to use a macro into the xpath, it doesn't work and no errors pop up. It clicks an area that doesn't match with the xpath. I use the chrome webdriver.

My code:

```
dob = 'Apr 18, 1967'

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., dob)]").click()
```

It works when I don't use the macro

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'Apr 18, 1967')]").click()
```

This is the area I am trying to interact with:

```
<span class="m-list-search__result-item-text">LastName, FirstName (Apr 18, 1967)</span>
```

This is what it interacts with when I use the macro in xpath:

```
<div id="sidePanelCollapseButton" class="m-stack__item m-stack__item--middle m-brand__tools">
```

I've tried locating with the class but the xpath for that would return several 10s of results, so going by the DOB is the easiest way to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you've been trying

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., dob)]").click()
```

is basically looking for a `span tag` that has `dob` as an innerText. Since `dob` is not actually present in `HTML` and it is a `var type`, you should use `f-Strings`, something like this:

```
dob = 'Apr 18, 1967'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[contains(., {dob})]").click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, although I've run into this error when running it
`InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[contains(., Apr 18, 1967)] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[contains(., Apr 18, 1967)]' is not a valid XPath expression.`
I'm guessing it is because the apostrophes between Apr 18, 1967 are missing?

Comment: Can you try with `driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[contains(text(), {dob})]").click()` ?

Comment: Also, to play around with apostrophe's you can use `driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[contains(text(), '{dob}')]").click()`

Comment: This error appears when I run the code above 
`ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`
I have a Wait of 5 seconds so that should be more than enough time for the result to show up, sorry if these issues seem amateur, I've only recently started learning this on my own

Comment: `ElementNotInteractableException` is a whole different error, I'd suggest you create a separate ticket for that. However, in this ticket, it is about parsing a var into an XPath, which we've tried to solve. It's about solving the `apostrophes` now. You can also play around with this `dob = "Apr 18, 1967"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//span[contains(text(), {dob})]').click()`, where we are defing dob in `""` and xpath in `''`

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I'll continue trying out different solutions to understand where the errors were sitting